# Web Search API with multiple search engines (Google, Yahoo, Bing)

Tags: javascript, java, google-app-engine, search-engine, web-search

I wanted to integrated some search engines(Google, Bing and Yahoo) in to my java application. I have looked at API's for Google and Bing separately, But I wanted to know can I get any open web search API with multiple search engines like Google Web Search API, Yahoo Boss and Bing Web Search API?

Ex: If I open my Firefox browser, at top right corner I am able to see the search tab where we can have an option to search with multiple search engines as shown in the following screen shot.

[image]

I need the similar solution. Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the search engines use their own url schema to search. It's really just a matter of working out how they build their urls for searching and then building an implementation of that. At least this is how your web browser does it.

If you're looking for an API in the sense of a native java/javascript (not sure which one you mean), you might be out of luck and have to build it yourself - which shouldn't be too much of a task.